# How to prove that End(R) is isomorphic to R?

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I tried to prove this: 
$R$ as a ring is isomorphic to $End(R)$, where $R$ is considered as a left $R$-module. The map of isomorphism is
$$F:R\to End(R), \quad   F(r)=fr,$$ 
where $fr(a)=ar$. And I define the multiplication in $End(R)$ by $(.)$, where $h.g=g\circ h$ for $g,h$ in $End(R)$.

Is this true?

Comment: You need to consider $R$ as a right $R$-module and the map should be left multiplication.

Comment: I can not change it , because I need to use it in wedderburn artinian theorem proof.

Comment: Then the statement is wrong: $\text{End}(_RR)$ is actually $R^{op}$. Either of these statements can be used to prove Artin-Wedderburn.

Comment: Can you tell me why it is wrong

Comment: The map you wrote down doesn't give left $R$-module homomorphisms. The other map you could write down ($F(r) = rf$) doesn't respect multiplication.

Comment: fr means indexed by r

Comment: My map is from a into ar under a map fr which indexed by r

Comment: @Bbbh Take another look at my answer: I switched to your use of $a$ and $r$. I have been trying to get you to see all of the points above with my solution.

Comment: Yes, ok about your word( run to a trouble)

Comment: Can I take the reverse composition and denoted by (.)

Comment: @Bbbh Qiaochu already spelled out what I was trying to get you to see for yourself: $\theta_{rs}\neq \theta_r\theta_s$. Yes, you can take the reverse, but in doing so you will be in $R^{op}$, not $R$.

Comment: @Bbbh or in ($End(_RR))^{op}$, if I misunderstood where you meant to take the reverse operation :)

Comment: And this R opposite , is it isomorphic to R

Comment: @Bbbh No, $R^{op}$ is nonisomorphic to $R$ in general. Still, it can be applied to prove the A-W theorem. I think Martin Isaacs takes that approach, so you should check out his proof in *Graduate Algebra*.

Comment: As I said I am having an exam tomorrow, and I don't have time to search for it, so I have to change it to right R module

Comment: How you show that $F$ is a surjective?

Answer (score 6):

It's true that: $a\mapsto ar$ is a left module homomorphism.

If we call this map $a\mapsto ar$ by $\theta_r$, then indeed $\theta:R\to End(_RR)$.

1. Check that it's additive.
2. Check that it's multiplicative. (You will absolutely need your rule that $f\circ g=g\cdot f$. The $\cdot$ operation you have given is the multiplication in $(End(R))^{op}$)

---

If you instead try to show that $R\cong End(R_R)$ in the same way (with $\theta_r$ denoting $a\mapsto ra$), you will have better luck. Can you spot where the two cases are different?

Comment: My map is not from r to ar , it is from a to ar under fr

Comment: @Bbbh OK! Yeah, I did misinterpret that slightly. I see now that in essence my $\theta_r$ is your $F(r)$ (There does not seem to be any point in writing "$fr$".) So you have indeed created a map from $R\to End(_RR)$. Everything I wrote still applies.

Answer (score 2):

With your definition of multiplication in $\def\End{\operatorname{End}}\End(R)$ the map is indeed an isomorphism.

Let's go slowly. We define, for $r\in R$,

$$
F(r)\colon R\to R,\quad x\mapsto xr
$$
It's probably better to use $F_r$ instead of $F(r)$, so
$$
F_r(x)=xr
$$
It's clear that $F_r$ is an $R$-module homomorphism; also
$$
F_r+F_s=F_{r+s}
$$
is a trivial verification.

Let's see what happens with $F_{rs}$:

$$
F_{rs}(x)=x(rs)=(xr)s=F_s(xr)=F_s\circ F_r(x)
$$
for all $x\in R$, therefore
$$
F_{rs}=F_s\circ F_r = F_r\cdot F_s
$$

We have proved that $F\colon R\to\End(R)$ is a ring homomorphism, as $F_1$ is clearly the identity.

Is it an isomorphism? If $F_r$ is the zero map, then $F_r(1)=0$, so $0=r1=r$. Thus $F$ is injective.

If $f\colon R\to R$ is a module homomorphism, set $r=f(1)$. Then

$$
F_r(x)=xr=xf(1)=f(x1)=f(x)
$$
We can push $x$ inside $f$ because $f$ is a homomorphism.

---

A common convention in module theory is to write morphisms of left modules on the right, but composing them "as written": so, if $f\colon L\to M$ and $g\colon M\to N$ are left module homomorphism, their composition is
$$
f\bullet g\colon L\to N,\quad (x)f\bullet g=((x)f)g
$$

With this convention, your map $F$ becomes an isomorphism between $R$ and $\End(R)$ without changing the operation on $\End(R)$: it's just the same, actually, but computations are more straightforward.

Comment: @rschwieb I use right to left composition throughout, except in the final part; the notation `\circ` means the "usual" composition, while `\cdot` is the product in $\mathrm{End}(R)$ as defined in the question.

Comment: @egreg Oh! I somehow didn't see that line before :) Sorry, I think everything looks good then.

Comment: How shall we show that $F$ is a surjective ?

Comment: @AlexanderLau An endomorphism is determined by the image of $1$.

Comment: @egreg got it , thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $F\in End(R)$. Put $a:=F(1)$, show that $F(x)=xa, \forall x\in R$.

Comment: Multiplying *on the left* is always a right $R$-module homomorphism, but not always a *left* $R$ module homomorphism.

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: This will end up being a ring homomorphism, but not from the ring $R$!  This answer will be misleading if you don't include that caveat...

Comment: I am having an exam tomorrow, so I don't have that much time, when I reverse the multiplication, I couldn't prove it , so I took it ar and I reverse the composition and put (.). Is this wrong